FORMULA PARA INCLUIR UNA HORA DENTRO DE UN RANGO HORARIO (SEXTILES)
Necesito una fórmula que al ingresar una hora determinada en Excel me diga en otra a que rango horario pertenece, para lo cual se dividió las 24 hrs. del día en 6 rangos horarios:
00:00 a 03:59
04:00 a 07:59
08:00 a 11:59
12:00 a 15:59
16:00 a 19:59
20:00 a 23:59
Ejemplo de como debería quedar estructurada la formula:


Puedes lograrlo fácilmente valiéndote de las siguientes piezas:

La función hour() para obtener la hora del número de serie representado en la columna A. Esto devolverá un número entero entre 0 y 23. Función hora() en español.
Al dividir este número de hora entre 4, obtenemos el número de sextil del día al que pertenece dicha hora
La función trunc() para quitar los decimales de la operación anterior, así nos quedamos con un número entero entre 0 y 5. Función truncar() en español.
La función switch() para "convertir" estos números en el rango de horas que representa el sextil. 0 es de 00:00 a 03:59, 1 es de 04:00 a 07:59, etc. Función cambiar() en español.

Todo junto, luce así:
=SWITCH(TRUNC(HOUR(A2)/4; 0); 0; "00:00 a 03:59"; 1; "04:00 a 07:59"; 2; "08:00 a 11:59"; 3; "12:00 a 15:59"; 4; "16:00 a 19:59"; 5; "20:00 a 23:59")

OJO: Uso Excel en inglés, es probable que los nombres de las funciones deban ajustarse al español si tu excel requiere las funciones en nuestro idioma.
Como puedes observar en la imagen, da el resultado que esperas:


GENIAL, TUVE QUE ADAPTARLA FóRMULA AL ESPAÑOL, TE PASASTE DE VERDAD, MUCHAS GRACIAS

@Javier, me alegra que la respuesta te sea de ayuda, un saludo!

Se puede hacer tambien con BUSCARV.
Primero hacer la tabla de rangos, algo así.

Al rango de horas, se le puede poner un nombre, yo le puse RangoHorario.
La formula puede quedar asi: =BUSCARV(E1,RangoHorario,3)
El resultado se ve asi:

